# Inverse Trigonometric Functions Concept Question: Where is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ located on the Unit Cicle and why?

Tags: calculus

Where is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ located on the Unit Cicle?

Comment: Why calculus tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what I think you mean is where is $e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}}$ on the unit circle?

$-\pi/2$ radians is $360-90$ degrees. So just travel 270 degrees.

You could also figure it out since $e^{-i \pi/2}=-i$, then you just locate $(0,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The unit circle uses a unit type called radians.  It takes 2$\pi$ to make a full rotation around the unit circle, so $\frac{\pi}{2}$ occurs at the 90 degree mark or a quarter turn.